# express.json() not helping in getting my request body params

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have the following in my app.ts, but I am trying to access the body of my request, which returns undefined.

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, Application } from 'express';
import express from 'express'
import chatRouter from './routes/chats.routes';
import  CustomError  from './exceptions/custom-error';

const app: Application = express();

// access body params especially when making a post/put request
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const apiLevelMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl, req.body);
    next()
}
```

basically, req.body is an empty object {}.

my postman call looks like this..

[image: Postman request]
what am I not doing correctly??

Comment: What does your request look like, client-wise?

Comment: @xehpuk, I am using a postman kind of request. i'll update my question with my request now

Comment: You added just a cropped screenshot of Postman. Export the request.

Comment: Your question contains insufficient information. We need the complete request (and server code) to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have registered middlewares for parsing request bodies with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `Content-Type: application/json`, but to parse `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` (which, according to your screenshot, you use), you need another middleware, for example, [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).